# JavaScript button isn't going to HttpPost Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $("#DSCreateForm").submit(); // part that isn't working correctly
            },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });

    var hobbsValue = $('#HobbsValue').val();

    alert(hobbsValue);

    if (hobbsValue == null || hobbsValue.length == 0) {
        $('.btnSubmitDS').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open')
            });

        });
    }
</script>
```

**CSHTML:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DailySummaries", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DSCreateForm" }))

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hobbs, "HOBBS:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hobbs, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "HobbsValue", @class = "form-control hobbs-textbox", @placeholder = "xxxx.x" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobbs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "...")] DailySummary dailySummary)
    {
```

In the above code, when the 'Yes' button is selected, it is submitting but when I debugged it isn't going to the HttpPost Method of the controller.  How do I get it to do so?

Comment: a [mcve] would be best here!

Comment: Do you have `method="post"` in your form tag?

Comment: please provide the view html as well and controller method signature

Comment: @JoeEnos just posted BeginForm

Comment: @Deep just posted view

Comment: Can you confirm that the URL of the form is as expected (view source on the original page), and check your network traffic to see if your post is as expected, and possibly remove the `BindAttribute` (at least temporarily) to try to remove anything which might be weird.

Comment: @JoeEnos When i go to create page on my app and view source this is what I get: `<form action="/DailySummaries/Create/13" id="DSCreateForm" method="post">`

Comment: That "13" is troubling. Is there any custom stuff in your routes config which might be causing that?

Comment: @JoeEnos yes it is the `id`

Comment: @JoeEnos any ideas on how to get that button click to go to HttpPost??

Comment: @JoeEnos well my `Get` method looks like this: `public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {` which is where the id is needed..

Comment: My bad on that - I didn't realize that the `id` gets dumped into the URL even though you're not providing it in the `BeginForm` arguments. I just recreated a simple example and it's routing properly to my post action, even with the id in the URL. So if it's not going to the post action method, where is it going? Is it going to the get method, or is it erroring out?

Comment: @JoeEnos Honestly I am not 100% sure.. I have put a breakpoint on the HttpPost Create method and once I hit the Create button, it goes into the dialog.. shows me the dialog and then I hit 'Yes' and the breakpoint is never hit.. I have tried the same on the HttpGet Create method and that doesn't get hit either

Comment: @JoeEnos holy cow, all I did was shut down VS and then restart comp, came back and it hit the breakpoint.. such a waste of time when it was going where we expected lol thanks for the help anyways man. much appreciated.

Comment: Ha! That's always my favorite solution. Must have been some cached assembly or something. Irritates me to no end - every now and then ASP.NET screws me over - I can't count how many hours I've wasted over the years chasing ghosts.

Comment: @JoeEnos haha i apologize but I just ran into something, even when that field has a value it is hitting the dialog box.. i only want that dialog box to be hit if the field is empty.. any ideas?

Comment: @JoeEnos nvmd I got it haha. again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the bold assumption that you haven't set
`method="post"`
On your form?

Edit: now you've supplied your form create code, I can see that isn't the case.